# Cannot create beta track in google play console. How to create manualy?

Tags: android, react-native, upload, google-developers-console, beta

I want to upload my app to beta track, but google console is giving me error that beta track already exists. How and where to find the beta track? Also not getting the option to promote alpha track to beta. Please help.

[image]